# ArcGIS Pro Tracing tool precision (decimal places)

Tags: arcgis-pro, tracing

Can I change the resolution/tolerance XZY of the ArcGIS Pro (2.9) tracing tool for tracing a feature?

I'm using EPSG 31255 (projection in meters) in the map. After tracing the vertices that are created have only 4 decimal places. I know that such a precision is not measurable, but I want that all lines and vertices lie accurate on top of each other. The coordinates of XY in this coordinate system have 6 decimal places, so I want this kind of accuracy, with snapping and tracing.

All I get are coordinates like 328133,**9093** 80647,**5373** when I trace a feature. What I need is a precision of 328133,**909279** 80647,**537321**.

So could I increase decimal places from 4 to 6?  Both features have resolution/tolerance XY that could handle this.

[image]
[image]

Comment: As I mentioned above I know that this kind of accuracy is not necessary. The coordinate precision and tolerance is appropriate for both feature classes (see image) - the one I trace and the one I create. In my opinion the quality of snapping will improve because there are not multiple points in a small area and data storage is no problem in this case.
But anyway I would like to have the same decimal places or coordinates for vertices at the same place. If I trace an object i get this kind of offset in some cases also if I trim a line, if I use edit vertices I can move the vertices precisely.

Comment: Accuracy and precision are not interchangeable terms, and you seem to be using them as if they were. Micron precision is only used in die sets for CPU microprocessor design, and at that point, it isn't stored as a Transverse Mercator. You can only map at six places of precision if you throw away your existing data and start over with a custom spatial reference. You'll need to read the Understanding Coordinate Management Esri whitepaper first.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me like a problem that can be solved with either the map topology tools or geodatabase topology. Either would let you align the edges of your features with each-other to a desired tolerance (by default 0.0001m).

Another feature that might be relevant is that you can adjust the resolution that vertices/points are snapped to when creating new feature classes/shapefiles. By default this also snaps features to a 0.0001m grid. I doubt this is something that can be adjusted after you create the feature class/shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by @Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428511/arcgis-pro-tracing-tool-precision-decimal-places/469743#comment699117_428511):

> It's unlikely that you have sub-millimeter accuracy, no matter what
> the precision is for the layer, especially if you're doing snapping.
> Coordinate precision and coordinate tolerance are properties of a
> feature class (or of a parent feature dataset, if present). They are
> only configurable at feature class/dataset creation, and are static
> from there on.  If you do increase the precision, it's likely that it
> will be harder to snap and trace (and your data storage will
> significantly increase as well).